# Incompatible Type for Argument 1 Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, dynamic, arguments

I have a function that sets an entity within a Core Data store. I used to have all values it would be storing as type double, however now I must make it accommodate NSStrings as well. Consequently, I changed the type of the parameter the function takes in, to an id type. However, now I get the error:

```
error: incompatible type for argument 1 of 'numberWithDouble:'
```

...at the following lines:

```
//...
[dfm setTimeStamp:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:value]];
//...
[[fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:0] setValue:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:value] forKey:@"timeStamp"];
//...
```

Apparently it doesn't like the [NSNumber numberWithDouble:value] segment of each line. I was contemplating making a container class that holds an NSNumber type (doesn't Apple already have a class like this?) to get around this problem, but I thought that there has to be an easier way I am not thinking of (besides duplicating the function and changing the type of the value parameter). Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

Here is the function declaration:

```
-(void)setItemInDFMWhilePreservingEntityUniquenessForItem:(attribute)attr withValue:(id)value
```

`attribute` is merely an enum which specifies which entity to store within. The problem is that the compiler is giving me problems with value being of type id, theoretically I can pass in anything I want, and I believe the way I have it I am implying that I will be passing it as an NSNumber, but the compiler doesn't like that as that is not actually a class instance I suppose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The problem is that the compiler is
>   giving me problems with value being of
>   type id, theoretically I can pass in
>   anything I want, and I believe the way
>   I have it I am implying that I will be
>   passing it as an NSNumber, but the
>   compiler doesn't like that as that is
>   not actually a class instance I
>   suppose?

By declaring `value` as id, you can pass any **object** you want. But why do you "suppose" that NSNumber isn't an object, when it's [clearly documented](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html) as being an object? The warning isn't about passing an NSNumber instance when you've declared `value` as an id - that's perfectly valid, because id means "any object," and an NSNumber instance is an object. The warning comes from calling [`+numberWithDouble:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSNumber/numberWithDouble%3a), a method that takes a `double` for its first argument, and passing it `value`, which is declared as `id` - i.e. an object. You can't pass an object to a method that expects a double.

Your proposed solution, typecasting value with `(NSInteger)value` will silence the warning, but it won't fix the problem. The typecast simply converts the memory address the object pointer targets to an integer value. If (as your edit suggests) value is already an NSNumber object, what do you hope to gain by creating another one, or by typecasting its memory address to an integer? Just do:

```
[dfm setTimeStamp:value];
```

Comment: Yeah my mistake, thought NSNumber was like an NSUInteger or NSInteger.

Comment: No, it's exactly the type of "container class" you said you wanted in the first place. :-)

Comment: Yeah, I realized that after I asked this question, heh.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies with the value variable. It should be declared as a double (primitive) for this call to succeed.

edit: after rereading your question, do a check in the function on the type of `value`, if it is an NSString (use `[value isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]`) store it as such, if its not then its a double (if thats the only two types you are passing) and store it as such.

Comment: What you are saying is all true, however it is not addressing my direct problem. It was declared as a double in the past and was fine, however I now need to pass in different types of parameters so I made value an id type and am having problems with that. Please see my edited post above.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just pass the `NSNumber` instead of `double`?

Answer (score 0):

Just realized that the call I was making (`numberWithDouble:`) was having the compiler check for a primitive, i.e. double. Changing it to the following worked like a charm:

```
[dfm setTimeStamp:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:(NSInteger)value]];
```

Thanks to those that responded!

Comment: That doesn't do what you think it does. All you're doing here is taking the address of the value pointer (all ids are pointers) and converting it to an integer type with a typecast. The typecast will tell the compiler not to emit the "incompatible type" warning, but it won't solve your problem, which is that value is a pointer to an object, not a numeric value.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I took your advice in your answer and works like a charm.